# Physics Simulation - Pushing an object with user control

Tags: physics, c

I'm working on a 2D game engine using C, SDL and OpenGL. Have worked out basic graphics, physics, and broad phase collision detection. I am trying to realistically simulate "pushing" objects around. I have gotten halfway there, but it doesn't feel right. I've implemented the impulse calculation found [here](http://www.myphysicslab.com/collision.html) to change linear and angular velocity. I want the blocks to have weight to them, and to slow the player down.

Consider [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QzhHdJ_Ef4Y). The leftmost block is player controlled. This is how my simulation feels right now.

Is there a relevant mathematical formula for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks perfectly fine to me (ignoring some jumping back/forth). To actually get the feeling of weight impulse isn't enough. You'll have to implement friction to slow things down based on their weight. Without friction you won't feel weight once an object is in motion (i.e. after applying an impulse).